# ng-pattern to allow numbers from certain range before and after decimal

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern

How to limit numbers for before and after the decimal point, something like before decimal should be from 0-30 and after decimal should be from 0-15

```
Correct: 30.15
Wrong: 30.16
Correct: 30.09 or 30.9
Correct: 0.15
Wrong: 0.16
Correct: 21.14
Wrong: 21.56
```

Looking for a regEx.

Comment: regEx. only validates elements quantity not element value. ex. ´[1-5]{1,2}´  this only checks that have 1 or 2 elements and each can be 1 to 5 but the order cant control.  I would recomend to check angularjs validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this for a solution? I know you said RegEx, but this could do the trick as well.

```
$scope.check = function(value) {

  console.log(value);
  var split = value.split('.');

  var part1Ok = split[0] <= 30;
  var part2Ok = split[1] <= 15;

  $scope.result = part1Ok && part2Ok;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nzTNdOR1eWZcwH5zYvIk?p=preview